# How to create shapes around mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a markup newbie and wanted to create some shapes like spider net around mouse cursor using javascript, jquery or even better, pure css (I doubt it is possible).

An exactly example is:

http://whois.domaintools.com/

Do you see shapes when you move your mouse cursor? What are these and is there any jquery plugin to do this?

thank you.

Comment: not a css/js expert, but I would say that you need to be able to generate visuals like this first . the location is not important. And then track where the mouse cursor is and place it there.

Comment: Just look into the source of the page. It likely contains some java stuff

Comment: Hey guys Thats HTML5 CANVAS  <canvas id="spiders" class="hidden-xs" width="1366" height="398"></canvas>

Comment: The effect you linked looks like it could be [ParticlesJS](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) with a blur filter and a circular mask around the cursor.

Comment: Is that site actually using ParticlesJS itself? I'm not sure how you could get it to be centred around the cursor using ParticlesJS (unless they've customised the code?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had used an a library for this. Here's the link to it: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js

It's just what you want. *Happy coding!*

Comment: Thank you. It was just what I wanted. Sorry, I can't vote up because of low reputation.

Comment: Lookiing for the same thing. Thanks for sharing about this. :D

Comment: Awesome, been trying to find this for a while. I believe Meteor.com used to have this on their homepage for a while aswell.

Comment: i seen but it not same example in http://whois.domaintools.com/.
Can VincentGarreau be customizable?